# Add 2 hours and 1 day onto a timestamp in django

Tags: python, django, time, timestamp

i have a model which holds data for a game, how would i add 2 hours and 1 day onto the 'starts' field?

```
class Game(models.Model):
    starts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ends = models.DateTimeField()
```

does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta
obj.starts += timedelta(days=1, hours=2)
```