# Timedelta on Django DateTimeField reverts changes after save

Tags: python, django, datetime, timedelta, python-datetime

I'm trying to exactly what is described here and seems straightforward enough:

[Add 2 hours and 1 day onto a timestamp in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383900/add-2-hours-and-1-day-onto-a-timestamp-in-django)

Here is my code:

```
new_event.EventDate += timedelta(hours = int(standard_time_offsets[request.user.member.timezone]))
new_event.save
print new_event.EventDate
```

The print statement returns the correctly adjusted date but when I check the record it has reverted to its value prior to the save. Im stumped, all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call the `save()` method.  The code should be:

```
new_event.save()
```

Note the parenthesis.

Comment: Wait this isn't Rails.... Haha thanks helping me figure that out. I'll delete this question.